# Datatables number of selected rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using [Datatables with selected extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) with [checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) and I am trying to get the number of the selected rows after I deselect one or all.

This code works perfectly with all deselection (I got always zero) but If I deselect only one row I get the number of selected rows plus one. It seems the event fire earlier somehow.

```
table.on('deselect', function(e, dt, type, indexes) {

  var numberOfSelectedRows = table.column(0).checkboxes.selected().length;

  // ...

});
```

If I wrap the code with a setTimeout It works perfectly, but it's messy.

Comment: check other events; i've encountered some APIs that have different events which fire as the change happens, but before the DOM has registered it as unchecked; another event might fire when the change happens, but AFTER the uncheck has registered with the DOM; hope that makes some sense..

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use rows_selected.length if you're following the jsfiddle provided by the checkboxes lab? So on click of the row/checkbox, just check the array length to see what the count is for what is still checked...